# pip3 broken after upgrade

Tags: python-3.x, linux, pip

I use python3.5 on Ubuntu 16.04 and after upgrading pip3, i am getting the following error:

```
**Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pip3", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())

  File "/home/xxx/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/__init__.py", line 16, in main
    from pip._internal.utils.entrypoints import _wrapper

  File "/home/xxx/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/_internal/utils/entrypoints.py", line 3, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.main import main

  File "/home/xxx/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/main.py", line 60
    sys.stderr.write(f"ERROR: {exc}")**
                                   ^
```

Looks like pip is broken and i don't know how to resolve this.
I have tried uninstalling and installing pip3. but it still gave me the same error.
Can anyone please help ?

Comment: wrong version of python

Answer (score 0):

Wrong Version of python,
since version 0.8, Pip supports pip{version}. You can use it the same as easy_install-{version}:

```
$ pip2.6 install otherpackage
$ pip2.7 install mybarpackage
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to install an old version of pip:

first of all delete current pip:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge python-pip
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo rm -f /usr/local/bin/pip
```

After that download and install pip for you python version:

```
curl  https://bootstrap.pypa.io/pip/3.5/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py
python get-pip.py
```